How to Proxy Content from One URL to Another Without Redirection Using Nginx Ingress
Could you help me with configuring an Nginx Ingress? I need to set up a redirection for the www.example.com/all-spots URL so that when a user visits it, they see the content of the www.example.com/spots page. However, the URL in the browser should stay as www.example.com/all-spots and not redirect to spots. How can I make sure that www.example.com/all-spots serves the content from www.example.com/spots without changing the URL in the address bar? Essentially, I want the content of www.example.com/spots to be displayed under the www.example.com/all-spots URL. How can I achieve this proxying without an actual URL redirect?
We tried adding below redirection in our nginx ingress. But it not worked.
location /all-spots {
        rewrite ^/all-spots(.*)$ /spots$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://spots.ecom.svc.cluster.local;
    }


You can achieve it by defining a proxy pass in nginx-ingress.Please refer to the SO link which might be useful to you.

@KiranKotturi  I added the configuration snippet below. However, the endpoint /all-locations is currently redirecting to /locations, which is not what we want. The URL should remain as /all-locations and the content of /locations should be displayed without a redirection.
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |

location /all-locations {
rewrite ^/all-locations(/|$)(.*) /locations/$2 break;
proxy_pass http://locations.ecom.svc.cluster.local;
}
name: url-rewrite

We don’t want the URL to change; it should work on the same page.
